# How to print variable from javascript code into html body?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a webpage that will give me the sunrise and sunset times and am using a script I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Triggertrap/sun-js). Below is my code...

```html
<!doctype html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="sun.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="hidden" id="sunrise" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="sunset" value="" />

<script>
navigator.geolocator.getCurrentPosition(function(position)){
 sunrise = new Date().sunrise(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
 sunset = new Date().sunset(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
}

document.getElementById('sunrise').value = sunrise;
document.getElementById('sunset').value = sunset;
</script>

//Want to put code here to print out the value of sunrise/sunset

 
</body>
</html>
```

How would I go about printing the variable value in the HTML body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `.value`, use `.innerHTML`.

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="sun.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="sunrise"></div>
<div id="sunset"></div>
<script>
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
 sunrise = new Date().sunrise(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
 sunset = new Date().sunset(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
})

document.getElementById('sunrise').innerHTML = sunrise;
document.getElementById('sunset').innerHTML = sunset;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I also fixed some syntax errors, and had to replace the `<input>`s with `<div>`s so the output could be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the 2 input lines since you will generate output:

```
<input type="hidden" id="sunrise" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="sunset" value="" />
```

Then you can use paragraphs instead.

```
<p id="sunrise"></p>
<p id="sunset"></p>

<script>
// your code..
document.getElementById('sunrise').innerHTML = sunrise;
document.getElementById('sunset').innerHTML = sunset;
</script>
```